# Text revolving around planet effect photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects

I want an effect where in I have a globe and I want to put a text ring around the globe.

Similar to the rings in a planet but in place of the ring, there would be text that gives effect of a ring. Can I do this in photoshop or illustrator. I tried to google for tutorials that do this, but wasnt able to find any. Can anybody help me out with this as I am new to both. I want kind of a 3D effect, so that it seems the text is going behind and coming out of the globe..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the tools in Photoshop CS3 requires you to find and learn a 3D program to get the effect you're looking for, but you CAN get there with Illustrator CS3.

I did a couple of tests, and was about to launch into a full-blown tutorial, but I recalled seeing Bert Monroy doing something of the sort, and found the [video on Revision3.com](http://revision3.com/pixelperfect/illustrator3d). Most of it's not totally relevant to your problem, but it's all useful stuff, and you'll need the info for what follows:

1. Set your text and convert it to a Symbol.
2. Create either a squat cylinder from a circle (using Effects > 3D > Extrude&Bevel) or a ring, by drawing a short vertical stroke and using Effects > 3D > Revolve, with an Offset of 200 pt (or whatever gives you a good size ring). Bert uses a cylinder, but we're going in a slightly different direction here.
3. In either case, play with the perspective and angle until you have the illusion of distance that you're looking for. Here are the settings I used for the Revolve version, so you can see the angles, perspective, etc.:

[image: 3D Revolve Dialog]

It doesn't much matter if you have a cylinder or a ring, just so you have a circular wall to put the text on.

4. Still in the 3D dialog, click on the Map Art... button. Add the text symbol to the correct face in the dialog. Bert's video gives you a great introduction to this dialog, and it's a lot better shown in a video than I could do here with screen grabs. When I was setting up my example here, I had to rotate the text 180 degrees (because of how I'd set it up in the first place) to get it to show right-side-up in the render.

Here's what mine looked like before turning on the "Invisible Geometry" checkbox:
[image: Text mapped on 3D ribbon]

And after:
[image: Mapped text with no background]

5. Save the AI file and bring it into Photoshop as a Smart Object.
6. Style and mask to taste. My quick-and-dirty test image is here:

[image: Final test image showing text in context]

This isn't a fancy demonstration, due to time constraints, and it's certainly not the only way to do this, but it should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

1) Place your text on a layer above the planet.
2) Select 3D -> New Shape from Layer -> Cylinder
3) Adjust your settings until you're happy with the effect.

Comment: In photoshop I do not have the 3D option anywhere and in Illustrator 3D options has only other 3 options and they are Bevel and Emboss, Rotate and Revolve.

Comment: Which version of Photoshop are you using? cs3+ has the 3D options available.

Comment: no, I have photoshop CS3 Extended..Is there any other way I can create this effect.

Comment: Can this be easily animated?  I've never worked with Photoshop's new 3D features.

Comment: @Kyle: From what I recall, there was no option to create a 3d object in CS3 Extended. That didn't come in until CS4.

Comment: @Alan: Yes actually I think you're right. CS3 could import 3D objects to be used in the artwork.. But CS4 can create them. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this for free that I can think of would be to download [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).  Find out how to do a text extrusion, and then find out how to bend it so that it looks like it's wrapped around a cylinder or sphere.  Render it with a black background, save it, and then bring it into photoshop.  Use the magic wand to select the completely black pixels and delete them.

If that doesn't work because parts of the text is also completely black due to shadows, then increase the ambient light slightly to make the shadows of the text just barely above pure black.  There are other, more professional ways of doing that, but that's the easiest.

If you need it to be animated, you'll have to find out how to do key frame animations.